# Correct spacing when using \sim as negation

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

When using `\sim` as a symbol for negation it gives incorrect spacing and this is clear if the spacing is compared to the spacing of `\lnot`:

[image: \sim gives bad spacing when used as negation compared to \lnot]

How can the spacing be corrected?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\(p \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot p\)

\(p \leftrightarrow \sim \sim p\)

\(\lnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\)

\(\sim (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\sim p \lor \sim q)\)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\sim` qualifies as a relation symbol, hence the "bizarre" spacing you get. Writing

```
\renewcommand{\lnot}{\mathord{\sim}}
```

allows you to later change your mind and to ensure symbol coherence, as you'd always write `\lnot`. If you prefer, use a different name:

```
\newcommand{\varlnot}{\mathord{\sim}}
```

The `\mathord` function is not strictly necessary, as `\newcommand{\varlnot}{{\sim}}` (note the extra pair of braces) would be sufficient to change `\sim` into an ordinary symbol, but being specific is never a bad idea (as barbara correctly remarks).

Comment: I want to use both in the same document (they are sometimes used to symbolize different sorts of negation). How can I redefine `\sim` so that it gets the same spacing properties as `\lnot`?

Comment: @N.N.: As @egreg suggests, use a different name. For example, `\newcommand{\simnot}{{\sim}}`. Note the double braces.

Comment: as noted in comments to another question, the class of `\lnot` is ultimately `\mathord`, which is equivalent to what you've got here.  but it's never a bad idea to be excruciatingly specific: `\newcommand{\varlnot}{\mathord{\sim}}`

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in other answers, `\sim` is defined as a relational symbol, to use it as `\lnot` you have to turn it into ordinary symbol using `\mathord` macro; `\mathord{\sim}` (this might give the same result as `{\sim}`, but it is always better to be more explicit), you can even wrap it in a new macro if you use it frequently:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\simnot}{\mathord{\sim}}

\begin{document}

\(p \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot p\)

\(p \leftrightarrow \simnot \simnot p\)

\(\lnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\)

\(\simnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\simnot p \lor \simnot q)\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `{\sim}` is the same thing as `\mathord{\sim}`, not as `\mathbin{\sim}` which gives wrong spacing here.

Comment: You can see in the second line that `\mathbin{\sim}` gives wrong spacing; a `\mathbin` becomes a `\mathord` when it can't be interpreted as an operation symbol, such as in `(-1)`: the second formula becomes "Ord Rel Ord Bin Ord", that's incorrect.

Comment: Since `\lnot` (which he was comparing to) is defined as a binaray operator, I think `\mathbin` not `\mathord` is what is desired here; `\simnot \simnot` is doing exactly as `\lnot \lnot` (I don't "read" math, so I can't tell what this double negation is supposed to mean and to tell if the spacing is right or not).

Comment: The definition of `\lnot` in `fontmath.ltx` is `\DeclareMathSymbol{\neg}{\mathord}{symbols}{"3A}` and then `\let\lnot=\neg`. `\simnot\simnot` is not spaced at all as `\lnot\lnot` as you can see by comparing the first and second lines of your image (there should be no space between the two `\sim` symbols).

Comment: I did not check the latex code, but `\show\lnot` gives me `\lnot=\mathchar"23A`, so that is class 2 (binary operator), or so I think.

Comment: No, because the first digit is in fact a zero (`"23A`=`"023A`), which is omitted by TeX when showing it and `0` is `\mathord`. The `2` is the font and the `3A` is the position in the font.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet: that makes much more sense now, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Could you please incorporate your update into your original answer (the whole answer is editable) because it still mentions `\mathbin`.

Comment: @N.N.: the update is there right in the bottom, I didn't feel like deleting the old text and claiming a wisdom I didn't have `:)`

Comment: You have the wisdom now! Also answering is about learning. It's a community effort! I think it's better to revise the old part to make it clearer for future visitors.

Comment: @N.N.: done now

Answer (score 2):

For my part, I find that `\sim` it too wavy. I prefer to define `\simnot` thus:

```
\newcommand*{\simnot}{\mathord{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textasciitilde}}}
```

The value used with `\raisebox` is determined empirically, however, depeding on the chosen font.

So this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}    
\newcommand*{\simnot}{\mathord{\raisebox{-4pt}{\textasciitilde}}}    
\begin{document}    
\(\simnot\cdot \) \quad (height comparison with \texttt{\textbackslash cdot})    
\(p \leftrightarrow \lnot \lnot p\)    
\(p \leftrightarrow \simnot \simnot p\)    
\(\lnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\)    
\(\simnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\simnot p \lor \simnot q)\)
\end{document}
```

gets rendered thus:
[image]